# Botão físico de voltar no Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-forms, xamarin.android

Preciso que ao ser clicado no botão Voltar do Smartphone seja retornado à página anterior.

Obs: Se possível não utilizar Navigation para não ter a barra lá em cima.

Comment: No meu app quando clico pra voltar ele fecha a aplicação deixando ela em segundo plano. Pesquisei no meu projeto 'OnBackButtonPressed' e em nenhum lugar ele está sendo utilizado.

Comment: Poxa vida, testei aqui e descobri o seguinte, se utilizo o  `Navigation.PushAsync(new Page1());` o Voltar físico realmente funciona, mas estou utilizando por padrão o `App.Current.MainPage = new Login();`, como posso proceder sem ter que aderir ao Navigation?

Comment: Muito grato pela instrução @Diego

Comment: @Diego, que tal colocar para Responder à minha pergunta para eu dar um Like? Acredito que dentro dessa comunidade seja importante, não consigo fazer isso num comentário.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voltar uma página ao clicar no botão <kbd>←</kbd> já é o comportamento nativo do Xamarin quando se está **navegando** entre páginas, a menos que você tenha sobrescrito o evento OnBackButtonPressed por algum motivo e esteja retornando `true` nesse método.

Para habilitar esse comportamenteo você deve usar uma pilha de navegação (controles providos na interface `INavigation` e implementados pela `NavigationPage`). Provavelmente você não está criando essa pilha corretamente.

Quando a página que está em exibição é já é a página raíz da pilha (ou a `MainPage` da aplicação), o botão voltar realmente leva o app para segundo plano.

Se o seu problema com a `NavigationPage` for somente a barra superior, você pode desabilitar sua exibição:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App.Views.MyPage"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"> 
</ContentPage>
```

Ou no código c# da página:

```
NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
```

Comment: Agradeço, ótimas dicas, não sabia que era possível desabilitar a barra do NavigationPage.